# Joomla setup redirect

Tags: redirect, joomla

I have a problem  in Joomla redirect manager component. I have 3000 links which I must redirect to new links. Is there some way to quick setup redirection in Joomla?

Comment: @Thomas W.: thanks for your edit. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla has an automated way to redirect links to a new url.

You have to select the links that you want and add a new destination url.
[image]

If you want to do it via database for all url, please try this query:

```
UPDATE `PREFIX_redirect_links` SET `new_url`='http://www.new_url.com', `published`=1 WHERE 1
```

* you have to change PREFIX with your database prefix.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, My all new links are different, So May I Insert data(old_url, new_url) to 'PREFIX_redirect_links' directly? Except the redirect_manager, and nobody update `PREFIX_redirect`?

Comment: Sure you could add them directly to the database table running an INSERT (not UPDATE) query.

Comment: Thanks, Before I have something wrong with operate the `PREFIX_redirect`,Now find the reason.Thank a lot.Good Weekend.